# Logic without content? Takeuti and Zaring

Tags: logic, foundations

I am reading the book "Introduction to Axiomatic Set Theory" by Takeuti and Zaring, and I wonder if I understand the "language of logic" from chapter 2 properly.

They write:

The language of our theory consists of
 - individual variables: $x_0, x_1,\ldots,$
 - a predicate constant $\in$.
 - logical symbols: $\lnot, \lor, \land, \rightarrow, \leftrightarrow, \forall, \exists,$
 - auxiliary symbols: $(\ ), [\ ]$.

What is confusing me is that they do not say what the meaning of any part of this language is. For instance, what kind of objects are the individual variables? How am I to understand the notion "$x_0\in x_1$"? And so on. Ultimately the individual variables are probably going to be sets, but there is no mention of sets at this point.

They later introduce the notion of "wffs" (well-formed formulas) as follows:
 - If $x$ and $y$ are individual variables then $x\in y$ is a wff.
 - If $\phi$ and $\psi$ are wffs then $\lnot\phi, \phi\lor\psi, \phi\land\psi, \phi\rightarrow\psi$ and $\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$ are wffs.
 - If $\phi$ is a wff and $x$ is an individual variable then $(\forall x)\phi$ and $(\exists x)\phi$ are wffs.

I try to answer my own confusion as follows, and I'd appreciate any further input: The language can stand as it is without having any meaning. It just contains some collection $x_0, x_1,\ldots$ of "things" (not necessarily countable) that we dub "individual variables", and it is unimportant where they come from. The important part is how we can combine the individual variables with the given symbols to obtain "legal expressions", and this is again independent of whichever meaning we can think of for the given symbols.

In short, the rules of the language are independent of any interpretation of its components.

Is this a correct explanation?

I can form some expression like $(x_1\in x_2)\land (x_3 \in x_4)$ without having the slightest idea what it means?

And maybe even worse, without having any idea how I can check if it's true or false?

Does it even make sense to ask if it is true or false?

I apologise for the somewhat "fuzzy" question, but I've tried to make clear the points of confusion, and I have a feeling that it can all be answered objectively.

Comment: It seems to me you don't know formal logic. Is that right? The short answer to your question is yes, you're correct. A formal system has both a syntax and a semantics. The "interpretation" or "meaning" is the semantics. The part of the book you refer to is developing the formal **syntax** of the language of set theory, not the semantics.

Comment: The **intended interpretation** of this formal system is: we imagine that the variables range over sets, and $x \in y$ means "$x$ is an element of the set $y$."

Comment: @symplectomorphic yes, that is correct. I have only done the standard propositional calculus that is part of any first discrete mathematics course, but there the different symbols have meaning (e.g. $\rightarrow$ is a conditional etc.), and you are able to assess the truth value of any formula given the truth values of its components. Here it seems that I cannot know if $(x_1\in x_2)\lor\lnot (x_1\in x_2)$ is true or not, and maybe the question is even ill-posed (if my understanding is correct).

Comment: You need to see the "basics" of first-order logic, with the concept of interpretation, that is the way to give "meaning" (i.e. the way to assess the truth-value) to formula. "Unfortunately", the way to manage variables is a little bit tricky... You can see Stephen Simpson, [Mathematical Logic](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/logic.pdf) (2013).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks, these notes look like they are filling in the blanks. I will have a look. There appears to be some difference in the setup of Simpson's notes compared to Takeuti and Zaring. Simpson allows the propositional atoms $p, q, r, \ldots$ to be formulas, while the individual variables $x_0,x_1,\ldots$ of Takeuti/Zaring are not formulas in themselves. I suppose Simpson hides what the propositions are about, and we just need to picture that $p,q,r,\ldots$ are some atomic claims, such as $1+1=2$ and $\exists x_1 \ \lnot \exists x_2 \ (x_2 \in x_1)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA to make a correspondence between Simpson and Takeuti & Zaring, would it be reasonable to say that the propositional atoms $p, q, r, \ldots$ of Simpson are all expressions of the form $x_i\in x_j$, where $x_i$ and $x_j$ range over all the individual variables of Takeuti and Zaring?

Comment: Please, do not mix Ch.1 and Ch.2 of Simpson. Set theory is a f-o theory; thus, you need *predicate calculus* language (Ch.2): the only *predicate* of set theory is $\in$ (*binary*, i.e. 2-ary; see **Definition 2.1.1**, page 24). Thus, the only *atomic* formulae (see **Definition 2.1.3.1**) are like $x_o \in x_1$, etc. Then see **2.2 Structures and Satisfiability** (page 26): the nonempty set $U_M$, called the *domain* or universe is our "intended" universe of *sets*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we need is the concept of *interpretation*: the interpretation is the way to "convey" the content into a *formal system*.

The first step is to pick up a *domain* (or *universe*), i.e. an "environment" of object.

The *variables* of the language will be used to refer to objects of the domain.

If we formalize e.g. elementary geometry, the variable will be used to refer to *points*.

In set theory, the variables will refer to *sets*.

Thus, a simple formula like:

> $\exists x_1 \ \lnot \exists x_2 \ (x_2 \in x_1)$

must be read as:

> "there is a *set* ($x_1$) such that **no** set belongs to it"

i.e. "there is an *empty* set."

---

Of course, when we formalize a theory, like *arithmetic* or *set theory*, we have in mind a "specific" interpretation, usually called "the *intended* one", but we can interpret a *formal system* in many ways.

The axioms of the theory must be *true* in that interpretation and consequently all *theorems* are true also in it (the theorems, being derived by the rules of logic from the axioms, are *logical consequences* of the axiom; thus, they are true in every interpretation satisfying the axiom).

But we can try with "alternative" interpretations.

If we consider e.g. as domain the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* number and we interpret the binary *predicate* symbols $\in$ with the relation "less than", we can easily verify that the above formula is *true* also in this new interpretation, because now it "means":

> $\exists x_1 \ \lnot \exists x_2 \ (x_2 < x_1)$

and the number *zero* satisfy it.

*Of course, this will not be true for other axioms of set theory* ...